Price an option based on given 2 stocks and 3 world states within 1 period
In a single period, two date economy, i.e. $t \in\{0,1\}$, there are 2 assets and 3 states of the world. The 3 states are - state 1: crisis with physical probability 0.05 - state 2: recession with physical probability 0.2 - state 3: expansion with physical probability 0.75 The vector of physical probabilities is $\mathbf{p}=[0.05,0.2,0.75]^{\top}$. - a stock with date-1 payoff vector $\mathbf{a}_1=[70,90,120]^{\top}$ - a real bond with date-1 payoff vector $\mathbf{a}_2=[100,100,100]^{\top}$ The date- 0 price of the stock is given by $$ \frac{\mathbf{p}^{\top} \mathbf{a}_1}{1+r+A} $$ where $r$ is the interest rate and $A$ is the risk premium. The date- 0 price of the bond is given by $$ \frac{100}{1+r} $$ (a) Find the price of a put option on the stock with a strike of 100 via replication as a function of $r$ and $A.$
A $\frac{1280}{19(1+r)}-\frac{2453}{38(1+r+A)}$ B $\frac{1281}{19(1+r)}-\frac{2453}{38(1+r+A)}$ C $\frac{1280}{19(1+r)}-\frac{2453}{38(1+r)}$ D $\frac{1180}{19(1+r)}-\frac{2453}{38(1+r)}$ $\mathrm{E} \frac{1280}{19(1-r)}-\frac{2453}{38(1+r)}$
